# Script nodeJS with this error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning NodeJS and i have a big problem.

Using ES6 and executing with `node --harmony`

`this` in my constructor tell me it from `Magic {}` whereas in `bar()` it from my Function.

I seek everywhere but i didn't find how to fix it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node --harmony

class Test {
    constructor() {
        var tab = []
        tab.push(this.bar)

        console.log(this) // Magic {}
        tab[0]("hello")
        // this.bar("world")
    }
    foo(str) {
        return str
    }
    bar(str) {
        console.log(this.foo(str)) // TypeError: this.foo is not a function
        console.log(this) // [ [Function: bar] ]
    }
}
new Test()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `tab.push(this.bar)`, it loses current context. You need to a) bind it: `tab.push(this.bar.bind(this))` or b) pass context when calling: `tab[0].call(this, "hello")`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind `this` in the constructor.

```
this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
```

Inside the constructor